# Can't load html file from Chrome extension file system

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to load an HTML file from the file system of my Chrome extension. I've added "modal.html" as a web accessible resource in my manifest:

```
{
  "name": "Test Extension",
  "action": {},
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "version": "0.1",
  "description": "Just learning for now",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "scripting",
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": [ "modal.html" ],
      "matches": [ "https://mypage.co.uk/*" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My background.js file tries to load modal.html with an xhr:

```
function initPage() {
  let node = document.createElement("div");
  node.setAttribute("id", "mySpecialId");
  document.body.appendChild(node);

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", chrome.runtime.getURL('modal.html'), true);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
      document.getElementById("mySpecialId").innerText = xhr.responseText;
    }
  }
  xhr.send();
}

chrome.action.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {
  chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId: tab.id },
    function: initPage
  });
});
```

I get the error:

```
Denying load of chrome-extension://lmdjgmkmficfccbahcpgnmaplajdljid/modal.html. Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension.
```

I'm sure this is a really basic problem, but I just can't figure it out.

Comment: Sounds like you're injecting the code in a page that's not covered by your `matches` in manifest.json.

Comment: Thanks, this pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by adding the `use_dynamic_url` key in the `web_accessible_resources` declaration:

```
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": [ "modal.html" ],
      "matches": [ "https://www.mypage.co.uk/*" ],
      "use_dynamic_url": true
    }
  ]
```

I don't yet understand why this worked though!

Edit: This was a bug in Chrome. The original code was correct and worked after a reboot.

Comment: The only explanation for this is a bug in Chrome because `use_dynamic_url` can't be a solution for the original problem, which means the actual problem was something else (most probably clicking the extension icon on a tab with a URL not covered by `matches`).

Comment: I think it might have been a bug in Chrome, as I had to reboot before I could get anything working. I've since removed the use_dynamic_url key from the manifest and it still works. Frustrating stuff!